# Принудительная инициализация свойств

Tags: c#

Есть абстрактный класс и производные от него.

Мне нужно, чтобы некоторые свойства абстрактного класса были обязательно проинициализированы `идвидивидуальными` значениями в производных классах, чтобы я при создании этих производных классов, не забыл назначать такому свойству значение в конструкторе производного класса.

Меня не устраивает значение по умолчанию абстрактного класса.

Вот в примере у производного класса `C` я случаной забыл `Prop2` назначить значение.

Как заметить что я забыл ?

```
    internal abstract class A 
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; protected set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; protected set; }

        public A(string prop) 
        {
            Prop1 = prop;
        }

    }

    internal abstract class B : A
    {
        protected B(string prop) : base(prop)
        {
            Prop2 = "Значение индивидуальное для производного B класса";
        }
    }

    internal abstract class C : A
    {
        protected C(string prop) : base(prop)
        {
            // Забыл добавить в Prop2 значение индивидуальное для производного С класса
        }
    }
```

Comment: Добавить в абстрактный класс конструктор (и убрать по умолчанию) который будет присваивать значение этомусвойству, тогда наследники будут обязаны его использовать

Comment: @ExplodingKitten оО, спасибо вам большое!

Comment: @ExplodingKitten Ой, такой момент, у меня есть уже не автоматический конструктор, который принимает 1 аргемент, который присвает значение одному из свойств, но помимо этого, мне нужно ещё другим свойствам присвоить ручками, как бы преднастройки каждого производного класса.

Comment: @ExplodingKitten обновил пост для понимания.

Comment: Что мешает задать свойству значение по умолчанию? (`public string Prop1 { get; protected set; } = "пример";`)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ обязательно разные значения свойства у производных

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я так понял, надо просто не забывать) или не использовать такое свойство в абстрактном классе и делать в каждом производном одной и той же сигнатуры свойство и давать своё значение ? Принудительно в абстактном классе этому свойству никакой модификатор не назначить чтобы компилятор следил за таким моментом ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так как я и писал в комментариях:

```cs
internal abstract class A 
{
    public string Prop1 { get; protected set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; protected set; }

    public A(string prop1, string prop2) 
    {
        Prop1 = prop1;
        Prop2 = prop2;
    }

}

internal abstract class B : A
{
    protected B(string prop) : base(prop, "Значение индивидуальное для производного B класса")
    {
    }
}

internal abstract class C : A
{
    // тут будет ошибка
    protected C(string prop)
    {
    }

    // и тут будет ошибка
    protected C(string prop) : base(prop)
    {
    }

    // тут ок
    protected C(string prop) : base(prop, "some value")
    {
    }
}
```

Если вы используете новые версии языка ([required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required) появилось в C# 11), то можно написать так:

```cs
internal abstract class A
{
    public required string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public required string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

тогда компилятор будет требовать, чтобы эти свойства были установлины явно, правда он не будет понимать, что эти свойства установлены через конструктор. Т.е. в наследнике вы не сможете в конструторе написать `Prop2 = "2"`. Потом просто создать `var c = new C();`, он все равно будет требовать `var c = new C { Prop1 ..., Prop2 ... };`.

Comment: оО, самое 1й вариант всё таки самое то, теперь понял, просто сначала не догнал как реализовать в итоге. Второй не подходит, так как через конструктор производного реализовать хочу. Спасибо, большое!

Answer (score 0):

Компилятор и так проверяет, что все поля и свойства инициализируются в конструкторе. Можно поднять приоритет этого сообщения (даже именно на этот контруктор с помощью директив препроцессора), чтобы оно вызывало ошибку.

Как вариант, можно в конструкторе абстрактного класса инициализировать переменные значениями, которые вызовут ошибку (правда, это будет ошибка времени исполнения), если в конструктор не были переданы значения для инициализации. Возможно, это не удастся сделать для всех типов данных.